# Reading a .docx file to extract the text along with font and other formatting information of the text

Tags: javascript, python, ms-word, python-docx, wordprocessingml

As the question states, my goal is to find a python library to extract the text and font information from a .docx file. For example for the following text: "**hello** *world*" I need to be able to read that the string hello is bold and not italicized and the string world is not bold and italicized. In addition to knowing if the text is bold or italicized, I also need to know other information such as size, color, font type (like ariel, times new roman), etc. I need to be able to read the entire .docx file and extract the information.

I have tried using python-docx library, and was able to extract the text but not the relevant font information in the .docx file. for example in the following code:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('cg0002.docx')
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        font = run.font
        is_bold = font.bold
```

I would get font and is_bold as none. Upon further research I learned that you cannot use the library to read the .docx font but you have to assign them your self. Is there any other library that I can use to achieve my goal?

Compromises I am willing to make: I am not particularly adamant on using python to solve this. I can use any other language like java, javascript, c/c++, powershell etc. I can also work with converting the documents into other formats like pdf if it makes it easier to extract the info, provided that the document stays intact (for example I could try to upload it to google docs and use appscript to try and extract the text but some fonts won't be retained once viewed using google docs, so I don't want to do that.

Comment: Your question assumes that all text formatting is done by local formatting (select text, use Format Font to change). Well constructed Word files use typestyles, not local formatting, so your code needs to be checking for the application of styles to the text, plus getting the characteristics of the style. In the case of numbered or bulleted text, this involves the type style plus a list styles. Tables use table styles as well. Your's is not a simple project.

Comment: @JohnKorchok is quite right. What you appear to be asking for is the "effective" character formatting, which involves resolving the "cascade" of the style hierarchy. This is similar to how CSS works, where styles are in "layers" and it's not trivial to compute which applies to a particular run of text. There is currently no API support for effective formatting in `python-docx` so you'd be on your own for that.

Comment: @JohnKorchok and scanny, thank you for your response. I guess I will approach this from a computer vision point of view. I am guessing it wouldn't be hard to write an algorithm to detect font styles to a 100% accuracy. I was just hoping that if I could extract these values from the file itself, I could save on processing time as my final product would potentially have to be applied on millions of documents. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DocX it would perhaps be 100% best to use VBA to garner the details.

However a "potential" alternative route might be to simply drop any style overrides by export from WordPad to basic RTF. Then look at redefined characteristics of target blocks.

NOTE:- depending on the conversion this may not be 100% reliable, to achieve you goal.

Whilst we can convert DocX to PDF using WordPad from the command line, we can not convert DocX to RTF without using a VBS macro, but that is a different question.

[image]
[image]

From the Header we can see CodePage=1252 & 2057= <strike>English (United Kingdom)</strike> British :-)

Breakdown by eye of
`\b\f0\fs24\lang9 Hello \b0\i World\ul\i0 !\ulnone\fs22\par`

```
\b - Is the start of Bold
\f0 - Calibri in the given language (BEWARE here 0 is an index NOT a stop)
\fs24 - Is points x 2 so the text here is 12 point
\lang9 - I forget at the moment, awaiting correction in comments :-)
 Hello - Has both a leading and trailing space (leading is to be ignored)
\b0 - My BAD, boldening STOPS, AFTER the space between the words
\i - Start italics (ignore the space before World)
\ul - Start underlining
\i0 - Stop italics (ignore the space before !)
\ulnone - Stop underline (don't ask me why not \ul0)
\fs22 - I will let you guess the default page font height but by now you know it is not 22

\par - THE END, "That's all Folks!" ™
```

**P.S.**

I revisited the source, to make 2 corrections, see if you can work out both changes. "My" clue to the second is above, but can easily trip you up when using regex.

`\b\f0\fs22\lang9 Hello,\i  \b0 World\ul\i0 !\ulnone\par`

whilst it should have finally been

`\b\f0\fs22\lang9 Hello,\b0  \i World\ul\i0 !\ulnone\par`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just realized I forgot to accept your answer. I am not actually familiar with how RTF works so I decided to use your first advice and go with vba scripts and I was able to achieve my goal. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it.